# XTicks in Matlab bar chart not aligned to their bars

Tags: matlab, histogram

I created a simple bar chart with the code below and notice the `Xtick`s are not centered under the bars that correspond to the odd number positions.  On the even number positions, they are.

I've played around with `XTickLabel` and `xticks` and I can't seem to get all of the `XTick`s to be centered under their corresponding bar. How can I get these bars in the right places?

```
hist(randi(5,1,100))
set(gca(), 'XTick', [1 2 3 4 5 ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is with the `hist` function, not with the ticks

```
>> [h,b]=hist(randi(5,1,100))
h =
   19    0   26    0   15    0    0   19    0   21
b =
   1.2000   1.6000   2.0000   2.4000   2.8000   3.2000   3.6000   4.0000   4.4000   4.8000
```

As you can see, it produces 10 equally-spaced bins in between the min and max values, 5 of those bins are empty. Instead you can do:

```
>> [h,b]=hist(randi(5,1,100),1:5)
h =
   16   21   18   24   21
b =
   1   2   3   4   5
```

The second argument indicates the bin centers. If you leave the output arguments away it will make a bar plot that has bars centered on the 5 integers in your data.

But `hist` is outdated, you should really be using [`histogram`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.histogram.html) instead. It will (almost) always do the right thing.